# How to query multiple repeated columns a BiqQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with 2 repeated fields. I'm trying to write a query that returns results for matches in both fields. In a typical SQL table, this could be achieved by using multiple AND statements, however when I do that, my table doesn't return any results. The table has the following schema:

```
[
            {
                "name": "id",
                "mode": "nullable",
                "type": "integer"
            },
            {
                "name": "record",
                "mode": "repeated",
                "type": "record",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "type",
                        "type": "string",
                        "mode": "nullable",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "category",
                        "type": "string",
                        "mode": "nullable"
                    }
                ]
            }

    ]
```

This statement gives no results

```
SELECT id FROM [dataset.table] where ((record.type = 'alpha' AND record.category = 'A') AND (record.type = 'beta' AND record.category = 'B'))
```

But this does:

```
SELECT id FROM [dataset.table] where ((record.type = 'alpha' AND record.category = 'A') OR (record.type = 'beta' AND record.category = 'B'))
```

How can I get it to return results that match ALL criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just output id of records which match your criteria, below will work

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT id
FROM yourTable 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(record) AS r 
    WHERE r IN (STRUCT('alpha','A'), STRUCT('beta','B')))
```

in case if you also want to output record itself with just those matching entries, check below query

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT id, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT *  FROM UNNEST(record) AS r 
    WHERE r IN (STRUCT('alpha','A'), STRUCT('beta','B'))
  ) AS record
FROM yourTable 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(record) AS r 
    WHERE r IN (STRUCT('alpha','A'), STRUCT('beta','B')))
```

or

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, 
    ARRAY(
      SELECT AS STRUCT *  FROM UNNEST(record) AS r 
      WHERE r IN (STRUCT('alpha','A'), STRUCT('beta','B'))
    ) AS record
  FROM yourTable 
)
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(record) > 0
```

If for whatever reason you are limited to Legacy SQL - see below, but consider [migrating your stuff to Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) as it is what Google BigQuery Team recommends!

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT id FROM (
  SELECT id,
    SUM((record.type = 'alpha' AND record.category = 'A') 
      OR (record.type = 'beta' AND record.category = 'B')
    ) WITHIN RECORD AS flag
  FROM yourTable
)
WHERE flag > 0
```

See more about [WITHIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#within) modifier for aggregate functions

Comment: #standardSQL
SELECT id
FROM yourTable 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(record) AS r 
    WHERE r IN (STRUCT('alpha','A'), STRUCT('beta','B'))) is only matching STRUCT('alpha','A') or STRUCT('beta','B'). How can I match for STRUCT('alpha','A') and STRUCT('beta','B'). Thanks

Comment: @Kwame - use last two examples in my answer with " > 0 " changed to " = 2"

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear what you mean by "match ALL criteria". Your first query uses following predicate

```
((record.type = 'alpha' AND record.category = 'A') AND
 (record.type = 'beta'  AND record.category = 'B'))
```

which is equivalent to

```
record.type = 'alpha' AND record.type = 'beta' AND
record.category = 'A' AND record.category = 'B'
```

Obviously `record.type = 'alpha' AND record.type = 'beta` is always `FALSE`.

Also, you don't have two repeated field, but rather single repeated record with two fields in it. So if you wanted to return ids when you have at least 2 repeated records, one satisfying `record.type = 'alpha' AND record.category = 'A'` and another one satisfying `record.type = 'beta'  AND record.category = 'B'` I suggest using Standard SQL:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id FROM dataset.table t
WHERE
 EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t.record r WHERE r.type = 'alpha' and r.category = 'A') AND
 EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t.record r WHERE r.type = 'beta' and r.category = 'B')
```